# How did my application database end up on the SD card?

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd

I have a question regarding database location on Android devices.

We don't specify where to install the app(no installLocation in manifest), but we see that ./data/data/{package-name}/databases are ending up on SD cards. On the Android doc it said that "When your application is installed on external storage, the .apk file is saved on external, but all private user data, databases.... are saved on the internal device memory."

My question is:

1. If the app was first installed on internal and the user decided to move it, does the databases and other user data also get moved to external SD card?
2. If no, then is there any other possible scenario as to why the database is now in external?

Any help/insight is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, afaik you can't install app on external storage completely yes on some phones you can move some apps to external storage but as I saw it only move a part of app which is still not readable by non root user, so sensitive or security interested files should always be on /data, so it must be flaw in app or particular os/device. Sure when you adopt SD card app can be installed on external storage but in adopted storage case it is not readable like when they was on internal. Is this question about development because that is considered as off topic here, maybe you should ask elsewhere..

Comment: Although the question is asked by a developer, IMO it's still relevant and potentially interesting to end users too.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. Yes I'm a developer, sorry if it's off topic, I didn't know that this was end user facing. Thanks!